# TinyMCE creating a custom button for customized ordered list

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tinymce on my website, and have the need to create a button that will implement ordered list eg `<ol type="a">`

Is there a plugin available that will do this? If not how can I create one that does this and also I need to keep the standard numbered ordered list

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is already implemented. Have a look at the buttons `bullist,numlist`.
All you need to do to activate the buttons in your buttonconfig of your tinymce init

```
theme_advanced_buttons1: "bullist,numlist,pluginx, pluginy,...",
```

Comment: bulllist equals bullets and numlist numbers, is there a shortcut that does the alphabet, or should I do this with inline styles or something.